# Getting and editing list of strings from file geodatabase

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, file-geodatabase

I have a file GDB that contains Annotation and Polygon feature classes. I would like to create a list of strings with the first part of the name of the polygon features. For example in the data below I would like to create a list that would appear like the following -

['Canal', 'CanalAreas']

[image: Data Example]

I have used ListFeatureClasses in order to get a list of all the polygon classes, but I'm a lot a loss of what the next step is, - a LEN() style function to move the last 6 characters?

```
lookfor = []
for dataset in arcpy.ListDatasets():
    for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*", "Polygon", dataset):
        lookfor.append(fc)

for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*", "Polygon"):
    lookfor.append(fc)
```

I currently have this list hard coded in another script and would like to make it more dynamic so I don't have to worry about data changes etc.

Comment: Do you want the part before the first underscore? fcBase = fc.split('_')[0] then if fcBase not in lookfor: lookfor.append(fcBase) - probably best to cast fc = fc.lower() first though to avoid multiple items with slightly different case (CanalAreas is not the same as canalareas). Also consider using arcpy.da.Walk https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/018w/018w00000023000000.htm then you won't have to loop for all standalone then all feature classes in feature datasets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you always want the part before first underscore then split at this and fetch first item (index 0) in split list. [Set will remove duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists).

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Default.gdb'
polygons = list(set([fc.split('_')[0] for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_type='POLYGON')]))
```

You can also use re module to [split at first non-letter charachter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35231285/python-how-to-split-a-string-by-non-alpha-characters):

```
import re
polygons = list(set([re.split('[^a-zA-Z]',fc)[0] for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_type='POLYGON')]))
```

Comment: Thanks Bera, this looks great. Upon using the code I noticed the first underscore was not always the right one, so I made a small adjustment like so -

polygons = list(set([fc[:-6] for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_type='POLYGON')]))